# The intersection of $w = x / \beta$ and a line parallel to $w = \beta x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, euclidean-geometry, physics, special-relativity

If you are familiar with physics, you may have guessed what the background is… but, the **following is simply a question of elementary geometry**. (Not consider the special relativity.)

**Question:**

> Consider the $x$-$w$ plane and $w=x/\beta$ (Red line of Fig.1) and $w=\beta x$ (Green line of Fig.1)
>   Under the following setting,
>
> - **Find the coordinates of $B$ and,**
> - **Find the length of $OB$ using $\lvert OA\rvert$ and $\beta$.**
>
> Detailed settings are as shown in the Figure.1 :
>
> - $O$ is the origin of $x$-$w$ plane,
> - $0<\beta<1$
> - $A$ is a point on the $x$-axis,
> - $\lvert OA\rvert$ represents the length of $OA$, and
> - The purple line on Fig.1 is a line that passing through the point $A$ and parallel to $w = \beta x$
> - $B$ is the intersection the purple line and $w = \beta x$.

[image]Fig.1

I tried to find the coordinates of $B$ and the length of $OB$ as follows. Is it correct?

**I tried to find…:**
The vertical leg from $B$ to the $x$-axis be denoted by $h$. 
We define k as follows:
$$k=1/\beta$$
Considering the trigonometric ratio, we get following:
$$\frac{\left(\left\lvert OA\right\rvert+\left\lvert Ah\right\rvert\right)}{\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert}=k \\
\frac{\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert}{\left\lvert Ah\right\rvert}=k.$$

Transform above equations step by step:
$$\left(\left\lvert OA\right\rvert+\left\lvert Ah\right\rvert\right)=k\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert \\
\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert=k\left\lvert Ah\right\rvert \\
\left\lvert Ah\right\rvert=\frac{\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert}{k} \\
\left(k\left\lvert OA\right\rvert+\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert\right)=k^2\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert \\
k\left\lvert OA\right\rvert = \left(k^2-1\right)\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert.$$

We get,
$$\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert = \left(\frac{k}{k^2-1}\right)\left\lvert OA\right\rvert \\
\left\lvert Ah\right\rvert = \left(\frac{1}{k^2-1}\right) \left\lvert OA\right\rvert,$$ and

$$\left\lvert Oh\right\rvert
=\left(\left\lvert OA\right\rvert+\left\lvert Ah\right\rvert\right)
=k\left\lvert Bh\right\rvert
=\left(\frac{k^2}{k^{2}-1}\right) \left\lvert OA\right\rvert.$$
Therefore, the Cartesian coordinate of $B$ is:
$$B
=\left(\left(\frac{k^2}{k^{2}-1}\right) \left\lvert OA\right\rvert , 
\left(\frac{1}{k^2-1}\right) \left\lvert OA\right\rvert
\right)
=\left(\frac{\left\lvert OA\right\rvert}{\left(\frac{1-\beta^2}{\beta^2}\right)}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\beta^2}, 1\right) \\
= \left(\frac{\left\lvert OA\right\rvert}{1-\beta^2}\right)\left(1, \beta^{2}\right).$$

And using Pythagorean theorem, the length of $OB$ is calculated as follows.
$$\left\lvert OB\right\rvert
=\frac{\left\lvert OA\right\rvert\sqrt{1+{\beta}^{2}}}{1-\beta^2}.$$

**Attachment:**
You can use PPT　version of Fig.1 from this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bO6K8qW-Mw4wCtIQsRDVGeGtdslPAvwu?usp=sharing).

**P.S.** I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions. I welcome any corrections and English review. (You can edit my question and description to improve them)

Comment: ＠amd　Thank you for your comment. Oops!!  I have mistake. I fixed my calculation error. The value seems to be consistent with the spatial relativity, if replacing Pythagorean theorem to hyperbolic metric. 
Please post your comment  as answer.

Comment: Perhaps it is necessary to replace β with 1 / β to match the special relativity.

Comment: Since you’ve changed your question, the comment is no longer relevant and having it as an answer would only confuse later readers.

Comment: Incidentally, it’s “special” relativity, not “spatial” relativity.

Comment: @amd  Thank you. Sorry to confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your geometrically-derived result looks correct. I would’ve computed the intersection of the two lines directly instead.

The equation of the green line is, as you wrote, $w=\beta x$, and setting $A=(a,0)$, the equation of the purple line is $w=(x-a)/\beta$. Expressing these two equations as homogeneous coordinate vectors, we find their intersection by computing their cross product $$\left(\beta,-1,0\right)\times\left(\frac1\beta,-1,-\frac a\beta\right) = \left(\frac a\beta,a,\frac1\beta-\beta\right)$$ and then dehomogenizing (dividing through by the last coordinate) to obtain $$B = \left(\frac a{1-\beta^2},\frac{a\beta}{1-\beta^2}\right) = \left(\frac1{1-\beta^2},\frac\beta{1-\beta^2}\right) \lvert OA\rvert.$$ Therefore $$\lvert OB\rvert = {\sqrt{1+\beta^2} \over 1-\beta^2} \lvert OA\rvert,$$ which agrees with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the notations provided by @amd, the green line is $w=\beta x$, the red line is $w=x/\beta$, and the purple line is $w=(x-a)/\beta$. For the intersection point $B$, we use the fact that $x$ and $w$ verify equations from both green and purple lines simultaneously
$$\begin{align}w&=\beta x\\w&=\frac{x-a}\beta\end{align}$$
This yields $$x-a=\beta^2x$$ which you can simplify to obtain $$x_B=\frac a{1-\beta^2}$$
for thew $w$ then $$w_B=\beta x_B$$
Then $$|OB|=\sqrt{x_B^2+w_B^2}=x_B\sqrt{1+\beta^2}=|OA|\frac{\sqrt{1+\beta^2}}{1-\beta^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.